# When I take "Time Machine" backup of Lightroom, does it backup my edits?

Tags: lightroom, backup, macbook

I´m wondering, if I take "Time Machine" of my Macbook Pro, does it backup Lightroom? And if it does, will my edits follow the picture?

Comment: Do you export your edits to XMP sidecar files? If not I would highly recommend turning this on in the preferences. See: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3154/why-employ-the-xmp-sidecar-file-in-lightroom

Comment: I would see saving XMPs as overdoing a bit. Decreases performance, and might be confusing. All you need is in lrcat file which you can move freely, backup, burn it on DVD or whatever. It makes sense only when you need to use camera RAW in PS, but of course then you can always open a copy of image directly in PS in PSD format and story it along with your photo.

Answer (score 4):

I am not Mac user, but as long as Time Machine will backup Lightroom catalog you'll have backup of your edits.

Lightroom catalog (lrcat file extension) is a database file where all edits and metadata are stored. It is universal file, so If you move it to other machine (preserving paths to photos) you will also be able to have you edits elsewhere.

Comment: Sure thing! :) If you use more then one machine it is good to keep catalog on external drive (preferably with RAID build in) along with photos you are referring to. However then I am not sure how Time Machine will behave. I'm using cloud backup solution.